# "Удмуртская кроватка" - возможно ли употребление такого словосочетания?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, возможно ли употреблять в речи словосочетание "удмуртская кроватка", т.е. детская кроватка, сделанная в республике Удмуртия (г. Можга), или правильнее будет сказать "кроватка из Удмуртии"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю,что выражение "удмуртская кроватка" (сделанная в Удмуртии) вполне допустимо в разговорной речи. Мы же можем сказать: белорусская мебель, удмуртская мебель.

Если это какая-то особенная кроватка, то нужны кавычки: "удмуртская" кроватка.

Дополнение

В современной практической грамматике всё чаще стало использоваться понятие "коммуникативности". Это означает, что следует учитывать не только семантику сообщения, но и его целевую направленность, а также всю ситуацию общения в целом.

Поэтому в каждом конкретном случае могут применяться различные  высказывания: (1)   В вашем магазине есть мебель из Удмуртии?" и  (2) "Мне эта удмуртская кроватка нравится больше".

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически сочетание безупречно. Стилистически - тоже.
Вопрос контекстного понимания не стоит, понятие самодостаточно. В чем проблема?
Неужели в фонетической трудности самого слова удмуртский?

Проблема коммуникативности, конечно, имеет место, но это уже что-то близкое к риторике, не та сфера, которая может может как-то сказаться на допустимости самого выражения.

Answer (score 0):

Да, такое употребление вполне допустимо. Ср., напр.: московский университет (институт, который находиться в Москве).

Answer (score 0):

Вас не поймут, только и всего. Сравнение с московским университетом и с белорусской мебелью некорректно.

Comment: Московский институт( тот, что находиться в Москве); удмуртская мебель( мебель, которая сделана там). Здесь одна и та же связь. Ср.напр: чехословацкая мебель, московские конфеты.

Comment: Если я скажу: "Я учился в московском институте" - меня поймут. А вот "Я купил удмуртскую кроватку" - меня не поймут точно.
Впрочем, если где-то удмуртские кроватки известны так же широко, как швейцарские часы - ради бога.